# Add method to existing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions in Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to add a method to the existing LoggerExtensions on Core 2.1 that will need to use IConfiguration to read some settings from the appsettings.json file.

I created a partial static class with my new method inside it but this does not allow me to access the IConfiguration as it is a static class.

How could I create this new method that is part of LoggerExtensions that can read from IConfiguration?

In the example below I can't access _configuration.GetSection as I can not inject it

```
public static partial class LoggerExtensions
    {
        public static void EmailError(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string message)
        {

            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(config.GetSection("Host").Value))
            {
                 // ......
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add some code that what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `IConfiguration` instance as a parameter to the extension method. For example:

```
public static void LogErrorAndEmail(this ILogger logger, IConfiguration configuration, Exception exception, string message, params object[] args)
{
    // ...
}
```

A better option might be to create a custom logger implementation which sends a mail under specific conditions. You can start by implementing the `ILogger` interface and implement your mail logic in the `Log` method. Inject the `IConfiguration` instance in the constructor. Secondly create a `ILoggerFactory` implementation to create a new instance of your custom logger, inject the `IConfigruation` parameter in the constructor as well and pass it to your logger. Finally call `services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, YourCustomLoggerProvider>()` in the startup class to register your custom logger.